# How to copy file to Azure Blob when using Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, yaml

I have tried so many times but still getting an error like below:

"The pipeline is not valid. Job Job: Step AzureFileCopy input ConnectedServiceNameARM references service connection xxxxx-xxx-xx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx which could not be found.The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz."

On the right side, there is a "Authorize resources" button. But whatever how I click it, it will show "An error occurred while auto-authorizing resources"

And here is part of my yaml file:

```
task: AzureFileCopy@3
inputs: 
    sourcePath:'AddFunction/bin/Debug/AddFunction.exe' 
    azureSubscription:'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx' 
    destination: AzureBlob 
    storage:'1234' 
    containerName: 'test'
```

Also I have connected the Service connections on the Azure Pipeline, and I chose the "Azure Resource Manager" for my resource type.

Any ideas or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to upload files to Azure Blob, you can do the exact same thing by Azure Cli in a Powershell script and trigger it through Powershell Task from Azure Pipeline.

```
# PowerShell
# Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    #targetType: 'filePath' # Optional. Options: filePath, inline
    #filePath: # Required when targetType
```

The Powershell script will be like

```
#First, You have to login with a service principal.
az login --service-principal -u $AZ_NAME -p $AZ_PWD --tenant $AZ_TENANT

#upload your file by az storage blob 
az storage blob upload --container-name $container_name --file $file_to_upload --name $blob_name
```

This may not be the perfect answer, but I hope it can help you and save your day.

Comment: Note that PowerShell is not supported for Lunix agents. Use PowershellCore for that (i.e. `scriptType: 'pscore'`) in Azure pipeline yml file.

Comment: or just use bash on Linux ;)